# Bootstrap 4 hiding issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, bootstrap-4

I have a simple row and 4 columns in there. it displays in one row as long as screen size is MD and above. I wanted to hide these columns so I have added two bootstrap classes in the row that are "d-none d-md-block" as per the documentation it should hide as soon as screen size goes below md.

But the output is weird, for some reason, my columns are not in one row anymore but it displays one below another.

any help??

here is the code, columns should be in one row as long as the screen size is larger than md.

```
<div class="d-none d-md-block row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is it:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.11.2/css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="d-none d-sm-block">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">1</div>
                <div class=" col ">2</div>
                <div class=" col">3</div>
                <div class=" col">4</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

you can check :  https://jsfiddle.net/sugandhnikhil/muxt6eg1/

Answer (score 0):

Just change `d-md-block` to `d-md-flex` and it'll work because by default row has `display:flex` property in Bootstrap and you are assigning it `display:block` property

```
<div class="d-none d-md-flex row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <div>4</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will check this, for now, I have added an additional die element on top of row and it did a trick!!